# Javascript insert a column into a 2d array

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Below is a table that contains the contents of a spreadsheet. I want to add a column between StudentNames and result3. I was wondering what the most "elegant" solution might be.

```
currentClass.push(["StudentNames","result3","result2", "result1"] ,
                  ["andy",55,33,22],
                  ["joyce",22,33,44],
                  ["Joe",22,11,22]
)       
var x = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("IST Green"). 

getRange(1,1,currentClass.length,4).setValues(currentClass);
```

// How do I add the following into col 1 of the above table  -> var y = ["result 4", 11,12,13];

Comment: take a look at the splice() method.

Comment: https://www.programiz.com/javascript/multidimensional-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function insertColumn() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const sh1 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  sh1.clearContents();
  let vs1_9 = sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),9).getValues();//9 columns
  let vs10 = sh.getRange(1,10,sh.getLastRow()).getValues();//1 column
  vs1_9.forEach((r,i) => {
    r.splice(2,0,vs10[i][0]);//insert the one column into column3
  });
  sh1.getRange(1,1,vs1_9.length,vs1_9[0].length).setValues(vs1_9);
}
```

Sheet0:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 | COL10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 14 | 5 | 10 | 17 | 1 | 15 | 10 | 2 | 6 |
| 12 | 10 | 2 | 19 | 2 | 1 | 19 | 6 | 10 | 7 |
| 4 | 7 | 17 | 11 | 17 | 3 | 8 | 7 | 2 | 5 |
| 10 | 17 | 14 | 13 | 2 | 6 | 18 | 6 | 1 | 11 |
| 15 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 19 | 9 | 1 | 4 | 14 |
| 1 | 6 | 8 | 8 | 7 | 10 | 5 | 5 | 17 | 12 |
| 15 | 1 | 8 | 4 | 5 | 7 | 13 | 19 | 0 | 7 |
| 14 | 18 | 9 | 10 | 13 | 3 | 9 | 9 | 19 | 14 |
| 11 | 1 | 5 | 17 | 17 | 15 | 2 | 6 | 8 | 16 |

Sheet1:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL10 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 14 | 6 | 5 | 10 | 17 | 1 | 15 | 10 | 2 |
| 12 | 10 | 7 | 2 | 19 | 2 | 1 | 19 | 6 | 10 |
| 4 | 7 | 5 | 17 | 11 | 17 | 3 | 8 | 7 | 2 |
| 10 | 17 | 11 | 14 | 13 | 2 | 6 | 18 | 6 | 1 |
| 15 | 3 | 14 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 19 | 9 | 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 6 | 12 | 8 | 8 | 7 | 10 | 5 | 5 | 17 |
| 15 | 1 | 7 | 8 | 4 | 5 | 7 | 13 | 19 | 0 |
| 14 | 18 | 14 | 9 | 10 | 13 | 3 | 9 | 9 | 19 |
| 11 | 1 | 16 | 5 | 17 | 17 | 15 | 2 | 6 | 8 |

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a way insert into existing data array, you can use [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method:

```js
const currentClass = [];
currentClass.push(["StudentNames", "result3", "result2", "result1"],
    ["andy", 55, 33, 22],
    ["joyce", 22, 33, 44],
    ["Joe", 22, 11, 22]
)
var y = ["result 4", 11, 12, 13];

function insertAtindexNotDistructive(array, data, index) {
    return [...array].map((a, i, b) => ((b = [...b[i]]).splice(index, 0, data[i]), b));
}

function insertAtindex(array, data, index) {
    return array.forEach((a, i) => array[i].splice(index, 0, data[i])), array;
}

console.log("not distructive", JSON.stringify(insertAtindexNotDistructive(currentClass, y, 1)));
console.log("orig", JSON.stringify(currentClass));

insertAtindex(currentClass, y, 1);
console.log("distructive orig", JSON.stringify(currentClass));
```