# How to append data to next column, using Google Sheets API?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I need to append data to a new column of a spreadsheet, every day.
But I want to make it automatically, just like `spreadsheets.values.append` does: but for columns.

**spreadsheets.values.append** will only append data to new rows, **not columns!**

I have tried these params:

- majorDimension does work for me:

> Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "majorDimension": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'majorDimension' could not be found in request message.

- InsertDataOption doesn't seem to make any difference

---

I'm sending data to a named range called "foo". When foo is already filled, the API places data at the bottom. I need the data to be place to the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could push each element of the new column into each row of the 2d array with something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68886835/7215091  In that case I used splice but you could probably use push instead.